# "if" statement not working on input variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I am a beginner and  my variable (`guess`) input doesn't work with the `if` statement:

When I put on the input numbers from `0` to `9`, I want it prints out `Right number!`, else it print out the other message:

```
guess = input("Choose a number between 0-9: ")
if guess <=9 and guess >=0:
    print("Right number!")
else:
    print("The number you entered is out of range try again!")
```

Comment: That's because your `guess` variable is a string (if you type in `9`, `guess` will be `'9'`). Convert it to an integer: `guess = int(input("Choose a number between 0-9: "))`

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a *string*, not a *number* (e. g. `"127"`, not `127`). You have to convert it to a number, e. g. with the help of `int()` function.

So instead of

```
guess = input("Choose a number between 0-9: ")
```

use

```
guess = int(input("Choose a number between 0-9: "))
```

to obtain an *integer* in `guest` variable, not a string.
Alternatively you may reach it in 2 statements - the first may be your original one, and the second will be a converting one:

```
guess = input("Choose a number between 0-9: ")
guess = int(guess)
```

---

*Note:*

Instead of

```
if guess <=9 and guess >=0:
```

you may write

```
if 0 <= guess <= 9:           # don't try it in other programming languages
```

or

```
if guess in range(10):        # 0 inclusive to 10 exclusive
```